# react-native-geolocation-service build issue

Tags: android, react-native

**Problem:**

I have a react native application, there I am using react-native-geolocation-service. After having npm install I tried to build the project using The android studio in there It failed and led me to an error like this.

> error: cannot find symbol variable ActivityCompat

This is my build Gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

I tried a lot to find a solution to this problem on the Internet but I was not able to do so. So can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

react native 0.60+ is migrated to Android X 
So you need to convert files into AndroidX  when add new library
use jetifier for this

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify (may take a while)
npx react-native run-android
```